# Idenitfying rows within a group which meets a condtion

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have  a table with the following

| ID | Days | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | F |
| 1 | 2 | F |
| 1 | 4 | T |
| 1 | 10 | F |
| 1 | 11 | F |
| 1 | 12 | T |
| 2 | 1 | F |
| 2 | 2 | F |
| 2 | 14 | T |
| 2 | 20 | F |
| 2 | 24 | T |
| 2 | 30 | F |

How do Identify all ids and days which fall between condition ==True.

For eg

ID 1 has day 4 condition =T

ID 1 has day 12 condition =T

similarly

ID 2 has day 14 condiiton =T

ID 2 has day 24 condiiton =T

Need all the days and Ids between these
the code will return ;

| ID | Days | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | T |
| 1 | 10 | F |
| 1 | 11 | F |
| 1 | 12 | T |
| 2 | 14 | T |
| 2 | 20 | F |
| 2 | 24 | T |

Iam looking for a dplyr solution but base R is also fine . Completely lost on how to do this ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. It should also work where there might be 2 ranges etc.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    n = cumsum(Condition)
  ) %>%
  filter(
    n %% 2 == 1 | Condition
  ) %>%
  select(-n)
```

edit: fixed typo

Comment: Although, there is a typo in the above which should be  group_by(ID) in the above clause , I think

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mask and use a filtering join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Days, ~Condition,
   1L,    1L,      FALSE,
   1L,    2L,      FALSE,
   1L,    4L,       TRUE,
   1L,   10L,      FALSE,
   1L,   11L,      FALSE,
   1L,   12L,       TRUE,
   2L,    1L,      FALSE,
   2L,    2L,      FALSE,
   2L,   14L,       TRUE,
   2L,   20L,      FALSE,
   2L,   24L,       TRUE,
   2L,   30L,      FALSE
  )


selcted_id_days <-
  data %>%
  filter(Condition) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    min = min(Days),
    max = max(Days)
  ) %>%
  mutate(range = min %>% map2(max, ~ seq(.x, .y))) %>%
  unnest(range) %>%
  distinct(ID, Days = range)

selcted_id_days
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>       ID  Days
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     1     4
#>  2     1     5
#>  3     1     6
#>  4     1     7
#>  5     1     8
#>  6     1     9
#>  7     1    10
#>  8     1    11
#>  9     1    12
#> 10     2    14
#> 11     2    15
#> 12     2    16
#> 13     2    17
#> 14     2    18
#> 15     2    19
#> 16     2    20
#> 17     2    21
#> 18     2    22
#> 19     2    23
#> 20     2    24

data %>% semi_join(selcted_id_days)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "Days")
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>      ID  Days Condition
#>   <int> <int> <lgl>    
#> 1     1     4 TRUE     
#> 2     1    10 FALSE    
#> 3     1    11 FALSE    
#> 4     1    12 TRUE     
#> 5     2    14 TRUE     
#> 6     2    20 FALSE    
#> 7     2    24 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hmm this wont work if we have multiple ranges within each group , right ?

Comment: @RobinPhilip Please elaborate the term "multiple ranges within group". My answer produces the desired output.

Comment: if Id 2 has  a futher  day at 25, condition =F  and id  2 at day 26 , with condition =T , will it still pick up these two ids and days ..

Comment: OK. Please clarify this in your question. You stated "Need all the days and Ids between these".